# C# SQL "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I've been learning how to create a SQL base with C# and I'm stuck here with a question.
Here I am testing how to return the value of a text row to a string

Why does the compiler make an error here? I read the method list and my database has 3 more values for the 'FirstName' column. Why can I only see an index?

I appreciate your help in advance

```
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        string dbName = "URI=file:testeDB.db";
        using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(dbName))
        {
            
            
            connection.Open();
            var command = connection.CreateCommand();
           
            command.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName FROM Persons";
            SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            Console.WriteLine(reader);
           

            if ( reader.Read() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Reading...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                string myVar = reader.GetString(2); //Index was outside the bounds of the array." 
                
                 Console.WriteLine(myVar);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Dont Read");
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `reader.GetString(0);` you have just *one* field (`FirstName`) in your SQL query

Comment: _reader.GetString(2)_ means _give me the value of the third column in current record of the resultset as a string_. You don't have three COLUMNS in that query but just one.

Comment: Third row is not the same thing as a third column.  You would have to loop through the reader.

Comment: Take a look at any DataReader sample, you'll see that you get access to the rows by looping through the rows.  You get access to the columns either by using an _ordinal_ number as the index in an expression like `reader.GetString(0);` or by using the column name: `reader.GetString("FirstName");`.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Comment: This error message usually appears if your trying to access a column that may not even exist in the database... i would check the database and that all its column names matches the same names in the code you are using to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the method GetString(int) as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader.getstring?view=msdata-sqlite-5.0.0#Microsoft_Data_Sqlite_SqliteDataReader_GetString_System_Int32_) says "Gets the value of the specified column as a String." and according to the code you showed us you are just retrieving one column from the table Persons, that's why you are getting the exception, only GetString(0) will work in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's kind  ridiculous I know xD, learning from nothing and being tired doesn't work. I will study that document calmly thx